# Multiple services behind one domainname

Tags: java, proxy, dns

I am currently working on a webbased Java EE application. In order to achieve multiple client capability I decided to set up the the whole application for each client on a separate server or to be exact on a separate Amazon EC2 instance. I am aware that this kind of strict separation may seem awkward but architectural constrains require the applications to be physically separated from each other. So what I got at the moment is the following:

IPa/client1

IPb/client2

Both pointing to more or less the same application with IPa and IPb being static IPs.

What I want to do now, is make these services accessible through one domainname like

mydomainname.com/client1

and

mydomainname.com/client2

while solely accessing mydomain.com will display some sort of login asking the user to define the client/workspace.

Coming up with this architecture I had some kind of proxy in my mind, so that the domainname points to that proxy, which then forwards the request to the right server according to the /client part. So all communication goes through this one proxy.

Does anyone know how to achieve such a thing? Is that how one would do it in the case described?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, a rewriting proxy would be able to handle this just fine, and in a larger application you'd be using a load-balancing frontend anyway. However, this question ought to go on Server Fault, since it's about server and network configuration, not programming specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I flagged the post myself concerning its misplacement in stackoverflow.

Comment: Hey @chrylis - I don't really think this is appropriate for Server Fault - while it will no doubt involve server/network configuration at some point, he's designing a system at present and really needs guidance with this design rather than the specific configuration. This actually *might* be appropriate on [webmasters.se] - but it should probably be reworked a bit for that.